# How to retrieve data returned from API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails and am using it to work with the Dynamics CRM API. I am able to retrieve the following data, which is assigned to the `@data` variable:

```
{"EntityName"=>"contact", "MinActiveRowVersion"=>-1, "MoreRecords"=>false, "PagingCookie"=>"<cookie page=\"1\"><contactid last=\"{D1092AB4-5452-E511-810C-C4346BB588F0}\" first=\"{D1092AB4-5452-E512-810C-C4346BB588F0}\" /></cookie>", "TotalRecordCount"=>-1, "TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded"=>false, :entities=>[#<DynamicsCRM::XML::Entity:0x007fe0813730e8 @logical_name="contact", @id="d1092ab2-5452-e511-810c-c4346bb588f0", @attributes={"territorycode"=>1, "owningbusinessunit"=>{"Id"=>"2daa0de5-a242-e511-8103-fc15b418f6ec", "LogicalName"=>"businessunit", "Name"=>nil}, "address2_shippingmethodcode"=>1}, @related_entities=nil>]}
```

I need to get the `@id` variable from that. I can get the `EntityName` by printing `@data.EntityName`, but when I try to do `@data.@id`, I get a syntax error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `@data[:entities]` ?

Comment: It's posted above, everything that is in the brackets [...]

Comment: Please show us the minimal code you're using to access the values that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of, but nothing works. `@data.entities.id`, `@data[:entities][id]`, nothing gets the id.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." Please read the linked page.

Comment: What are you talking about? I did all of that, I included all of the relevant code and need to know how to get a specific variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `@data.entities.id`.Because `id` is inside `entities` key of @data.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I got the error 'undefined method "id"'.